# How can I close or minimize the Windows 10 on screen Keyboard using JAVA?

Tags: java, processing, minimize, taskkill, on-screen-keyboard

I have tried executing a taskkill to shut down the On screen Keyboard in windows 10 (OSK.exe), but the OSK seems to behave differently in windows 10... while I can launch the application, I cant shut it down as before with taskkill.  Even in the command prompt I get an access denied error...
I would settle for the ability to at least minimize it, but that is something I don't know how to do.. any suggestions?
My processing line looks like this

```
public void onScreenKbdMain_click1(GImageButton source, GEvent event) { 
  println("onScreenKbdMain - GImageButton >> GEvent." + event + " @ " + millis());
  if (keyboardOnOff == false) {
    sentense="Onscreen keyboard activated";
    String[] params = { 
      "C:/bala/bala.exe", "-t", sentense
    }; 
    launch(params);
    //pKeyboard = open(new String[] { "c:/Windows/system32/osk.exe" } ); // Windows Keyboard
    pKeyboard = launch(new String[] { 
      "osk"
      } 
      ); // Windows Keyboard
    keyboardOnOff=!keyboardOnOff;
    //println("keyboardOnOff= "+keyboardOnOff);
  } else {
    sentense="Onscreen keyboard disabled";
    String[] params = { 
      "C:/bala/bala.exe", "-t", sentense
    }; 
    launch(params);
    pKeyboard = launch(new String[] { 
      "taskkill IM/osk.exe/T/F"
      } 
      ); // Windows Keyboard
    keyboardOnOff=!keyboardOnOff;
    //println("keyboardOnOff= "+keyboardOnOff);
  }
}
```

Comment: Why would you want to close the onscreen keyboard? And isnt that file "OSK.exe" only accessable administrator permissions?

Comment: I suspect `new String[] { "taskkill IM/osk.exe/T/F" }` should be `new String[] { "taskkill", "/IM", "osk.exe", "/T", "/F" }`.

Comment: I call up osk as needed but need it gone or at least minimized the rest of the time.... I have to do it from within the processing/java app

Comment: I will try your suggestion and see if that helps

Comment: I tried new String[] { "taskkill", "/IM", "osk.exe", "/T", "/F" } but got the same results...  it is definitely a security issue in windows... I tried this in the command prompt and got an "access denied" error....

Answer (score 0):

Check my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71410876/12346089 is using TabTip.exe instead of osk.exe but it may work for you.